# How to provide test retrofit url with Hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, mockwebserver, dagger-hilt

In my application I started to use Hilt as DI. So I create a class to provide retrofit in in my repository like this

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RetrofitModule {

    var baseUrl = "https://my.fancy.api"


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofitClient(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(providesOkHttpClient())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesJokeGeneratorService(retrofit: Retrofit): FancyApiService {
        return retrofit.create(FancyApiService::class.java)
    }
```

My question, how can I change the url to use it in the Mockwebserver with Hilt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your module from `object` to `class` and make the `baseUrl` variable `open`:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
open class RetrofitModule {

    open var baseUrl = "https://my.fancy.api"


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofitClient(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(providesOkHttpClient())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesJokeGeneratorService(retrofit: Retrofit): FancyApiService {
        return retrofit.create(FancyApiService::class.java)
    }
```

Then simply create a new test module inside your test source:

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [RetrofitModule::class]
)
class TestRetrofitModule : RetrofitModule() {
    override var baseUrl = "https://localhost:8000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different build variants to separate mock from real, you can create two classes with exact name in both mock and real package and extent `RetrofitModule` from that class. Then put differences such as `baseUrl` and etc. in those two classes.

```
class RetrofitModuleConstants {

    val baseUrl = "https://my.fancy.api"
}

@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RetrofitModule : RetrofitModuleConstants  {
    ...
}
```